# Config file in resources not loaded during unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, classpath

I have this line in a constructor `AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rabbitmq-config.spring.xml");` that's throwing an exception when initializing the class in a unit test: `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null`

*rabbitmq-config.spring.xml* is in *src/main/resources*, the class that's loading it in *src/main/java* and the test class in *src/test/java*. I tried copying the XML file in *src/test/resources* but it didn't help.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I had a `spring-beans` dependency in the POM and another one with a different version in the parent POM. Removed one of them and problem was fixed.